# Equal apk's with different languages: will the user pick the correct one?

Tags: android

As you know, on Google Play it's possible to publish more versions of apk, and the user will automatically select the right apk based on his device, for example according to the screen size or the OS version.

I was wondering: is this possible also with languages?

I have a very large apk that includes something like 30+ languages, each of it weights 150Kb on the apk (compressed). This is a bad thing on distribution, and reducing the number of languages in the apk would be a good thing, both on user side, both on number of downloads.
I would be happy to let the user save 4Mb of download, but I don't want to lose the users of other countries.

So, if I publish for example 3 apk's, with 3 different version numbers, each of them with a different set of languages, but equal to the others for all the other aspects, will the user download the correct apk according to the language he is using (for example on Google Play, or on his device)?

This solution would guarantee the users to download only useful languages, and on the other side will serve users from all the countries. Will it work?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the mobile will take default language of applicaiton which is default language of device..if i using marathi as device language and if ur application supports marathi language then it will download that particular apk

Comment: Don't got that route... really this is a bad idea! Also you talk about 4MB of download. 4MB! This is NOTHING... see games and more who requires multiple hundreds of MB to work..

Comment: I don't agree, WarrenFaith... if you talk about small apps, the difference between a 8MB app and a 2MB or 3MB is really huge, and can determine a big download decrease: it is even suggested by AppBrain's Apptimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

> By publishing your application with multiple APKs, you can:
>
> - Support different OpenGL texture compression formats with each APK.
> - Support different screen sizes and densities with each APK.
> - Support different platform versions with each APK.
> - Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS, when your app uses the Android NDK).
>
> Currently, these are the only device characteristics that Google Play
>   supports for publishing multiple APKs as the same application.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this: [Language resources in separate APK?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2702729/1432239)

Comment: A nice solution but looks a little bit too complex for users, I think. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In a literal way, multi-APK for language is impossible, but there's a better way to add translations for every language And solve your problem, but you should use XML, [Translate & localize your app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en)  (instead of paid translations you can add your own):